# Type text into iTerm terminal from apple script

Tags: mac, applescript, iterm

I'm trying to paste text from apple script to iTerm.

```
activate application "iTerm"
tell application "iTerm"
    tell current tab of current window
        set cmd to "command"
        keystroke cmd
        keystroke return
    end tell
end tell
```

But i'm getting an error:

> iTerm got an error: Can’t get keystroke "command" of current tab of
>   current window.

Any ideas how to fix this?

As I here there is available `write text` command https://www.iterm2.com/documentation-scripting.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `write text` *command* is done within the `current session`, so use the following *example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```
activate application "iTerm"
tell application "iTerm"
    tell current session of current window
        set cmd to "command"
        write text cmd
    end tell
end tell
```

To use the `keystroke` *command* use `System Events`:

```
activate application "iTerm"
tell application "iTerm"
    tell current tab of current window
        set cmd to "command"
        tell application "System Events"
            keystroke cmd
            keystroke return
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

**Note:** You may need to strategically place a `delay` *command* to allow **iTerm** to fully activate before the `write text` or `keystroke` *commands* are executed.